# How to get rid of message "Windows could not check for updates automatically"?

Tags: windows-7, notifications, notification-area, action-center

I have a managed Windows 7 PC, on which I don't have control over the download and installation of Windows updates. In my Action Center notification icon in the taskbar I keep having the message

```
Windows could not check for updates automatically. (Important)
```

along with other notifications. However, since I have no control over Windows updates, is there a way to stop being notified about the presence of new updates?

Comment: You would need to adjust the group policy that controls this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speak to the person or team that manages the Windows 7 PC.  They can control this through a Group Policy or whatever they use to manage the systems.